# How can I make the coroutine to start and keep working while the others are already in action?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The script is attached to 3 cubes.
Each cube with another tag.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class raytest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float duration;
    public string tag;

    private Vector3 originalpos;

    private void Start()
    {
        originalpos = transform.position;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100))
        {
            if (hit.transform.tag == tag)
            {
                 if (transform.position.z != originalpos.z - 1)
                   StartCoroutine(moveToX(transform, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z - 1), duration));
            }
            else
            {
                 StartCoroutine(moveToX(transform, originalpos, duration));
            }
        }
        else
        {
             //reset
             StartCoroutine(moveToX(transform, originalpos, duration));
        }
    }

    bool isMoving = false;
    IEnumerator moveToX(Transform fromPosition, Vector3 toPosition, float duration)
    {
        //Make sure there is only one instance of this function running
        if (isMoving)
        {
            yield break; ///exit if this is still running
        }
        isMoving = true;

        float counter = 0;

        //Get the current position of the object to be moved
        Vector3 startPos = fromPosition.position;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            fromPosition.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, toPosition, counter / duration);
            yield return null;
        }

        isMoving = false;
    }
}
```

When the mouse is over a gameobject and shoot a ray the object start moving.
When the ray is not hitting the object the object is moving back to it's original place.

But sometimes when I move the mouse over two or even three objects quick the next object is not moving until the first one finished moving.
Sometimes the objects are moving at the same time the first one move forward while the rest still moving back to original position.

I'm not sure why sometimes when hitting another object it's waiting first for the other to back to it's original position and only then start moving the hitting one ? And not moving them at the same time one forward and one back.

The idea is that if I hit a object and start moving forward once I'm hitting another object the first one should start moving back and the one that is hitting should start moving forward parallelly.

Comment: I suspect the issue arises when you mouse over an object, leave that object, and return *to it again* before the animation finishes. In which case you have two coroutines that are essentially fighting each other.

Comment: I'm not sure that calling `StartCoroutine` *every frame* is the best approach. Why aren't you just implementing this logic directly in `Update()`?

Comment: Also, `transform.position.z != originalpos.z - 1` - don't do that. Floating point errors accumulate over time and eventually you'll wind up with a difference of something like 0.99999 rather than 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if I don't understand the question properly, but this is what I gather:

If the raycast is hitting an object then its moving one way, if the raycast is not hitting an object then its moving back to its original place.

If this is all you need - aren't coroutines over complicating the issue? For example, you could have a `CheckIfRaycast.cs` script attached to each of your boxes. Inside that scripts `Update()`method you could check if its being hit with the raycast or not, then do your desired movement.

Multiple coroutines can cause some strange behaviour, so make sure you stop them with `StopCoroutine(coroutine name);` or `StopAllCoroutines();`.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopAllCoroutines.html

Answer (score 1):

you should identify you coroutines that way:

you have to use different coroutines on different objects

```
Coroutine c1;
Coroutine c2;

void runCourotines()
{
    c1 = StartCoroutine(MoveToX());
    c2 = StartCoroutine(MoveToX());
}

void StopCoroutines()
{
    StopCoroutine(c1);
}
```